# Cold planet with ongoing political wars and segregated society

Tags: story-identification, books

**This has spoilers in it!**

I remember reading a book set on another planet, where there were people with deformities, like extra fingers, and the planet would go through long periods of cold. It would get so cold at night, that the prospect of being caught outdoors as night was falling would cause people to go insane, and they would die from the cold.

The story is set through the eyes of a young man, who as a boy was caught in the cold and these, unseen and unknown, hairy people took him in for the night and kept him safe. A rare experience.

The government propagates  faux wars with other countries and the history books are continually being shredded and rewritten, depending upon, who is supposed to be the current ally and enemy. It turns out this is used to hide a larger agenda; a long period of cold that few will survive. The main character's father works for the government and they are promised to be housed. As the cold sets in the general population are fenced outside of the government compound and the government employees and their families are safely ensconced in the building made to keep them warm for the cold period.

Of course there is a romantic thread and our main character's girlfriend is locked outside the compound, left with the others to freeze to death.

Finally one cold morning they wake up and notice the heating has been turned off their floor, the government officials in higher places are housed further down in the bunker and it proves that the promise of safety was a ruse to gain cooperation from employees and that only a few select of the selected group will indeed be saved. So the main character's family is doomed to freeze to death.

It is at this point our main character heads off to the bushes where these unseen hairy people are and they take him in his hazy state and keep him warm. The book ends.

I cannot for the life of me, remember the title or the author.

Comment: About when did you read it and how new was it (if you know) at that time ?  Would you classify as young adult ?

Comment: @stan I read it nearly 30 years ago. I don't know how old it was at the time. I would classify it as reading for a young adult or adult reading. A friend lent it to me to read. I read it at the same time as the other one I posted on here and as reading p farmers books. To your scattered bodies go

Comment: @Stan cannot for the life of me find it. gr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm almost certain that this is Michael Coney’s Hello Summer, Goodbye (title was Rax in the USA and Pallahaxi Tide in Canada).  There's a good outline of the story [here](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2010/08/growing-up-alien-michael-coneys-hello-summer-goodbye).  Even if it isn't the book your after I recommend it - a strange read but I found it very memorable.

Comment: I'm thinking it must be it, but for the life of me the title and author do not ring a bell, but that would not be surprising, given he's a little known author, it was a book a boyfriend lent me and I read it and returned it, I actually enjoyed the story it took me on. Good find. How did you find it? You must've read it? cheers Jackson

Comment: I read this many years ago when it first came out and I must admit it's been re-read a few times since then. You might also be interested to know that there is a sequel called 'I Remember Pallahaxi'.

Comment: Hm didn't know about the sequel, it lent itself to a sequel

Comment: When he became terminally ill he made some of his novels available for free download http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/I_Remember_Pallahaxi.pdf